# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, automatically filling a field with values from another field?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I generated the following code on DeZign for databases but it doesn't work as I expected, it does create the tables and everything seems to work fine until I insert information in the OrderDetails table, I need it to automatically fill the "unitPrice" field from the "OrderDetails" table with the values stored in the "unitPrice" field from the "Products" table...
Is there any way to achieve this?

```
CREATE TABLE [Products] (
[productID] NUMERIC IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[productName] VARCHAR(40),
[unitPrice] DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
[unitsInStock] INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY ([productID], [unitPrice])
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [OrderDetails] (
[orderID] NUMERIC IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[productID] NUMERIC NOT NULL,
[unitPrice] DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderDetails] PRIMARY KEY ([orderID], [productID], [unitPrice])
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [OrderDetails] ADD CONSTRAINT [Products_OrderDetails] 
FOREIGN KEY ([productID], [unitPrice]) REFERENCES [Products] ([productID],[unitPrice])
GO
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By running alter table you are not updating any values with anything.  You'd need to run a set of update statements for that

Comment: I already know that, the code I posted in the question was only intended to show how I generated the tables

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use an INSERT trigger but why would you want to do this?
If you were going to find the price of an item would you just not want to do a JOIN between the OrderDetails and and Products table based on the productID of the item?

```
SELECT p.unitPrice FROM orderDetails AS od
JOIN Products AS p ON od.productId=p.productId
```